# Why is the Query Execution Plan on my test-environment different from live-server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I restored a sql-backup into my test-server. One of the major queries runs slow, so I inspected it with estimated and actual execution plans, made some indecies to speed it up.

Checking the live-server to see how slow the query runs with the more powerful server, the estimated and actual execution plans both show that something is already optimized.

Apparently MS SQL Server has automatic tuning. Is it possible that the server already optimized the live database? How would I check that?

Edit: I think I am looking for query-statistics

Comment: [`DBCC SHOW_STATISTICS ('schema.table', [Index_Name]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-show-statistics-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) will give you when the statistics on an index were last updated. That might shed some light on the situation. You should certainly be able to compare the differences between your production database and your backup.

Comment: Also, if the two machines have a different number of processors, the MAXDOP setting will be different, which could change the execution plan.  Same for the treshhold for parallelism server settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Brent Ozarks "post execution plan" and post the plans. Provided its a current backup and all things are equal, such as the data, number of rows, etc. indices all online, SQL Server version.

SQL version, for example, is important because of changes with the cardinality estimator. This will certainly change things. Are the server-level MAXDOP settings the same? If ypur test server is set to 1 or two and the other has 16 CPUS, then the Test server query might not get a badly needed execution plan. I had a 23,000,000 row query once that went from 45 minutes to a minute once we fixed the MAXDOP settings (this is an example of what can be wrong NOT a recommendation.)

> > so I inspected it with estimated and actual execution plans, made some indecies to speed it up.

I would avoid this and try to understand why the plans are different first. New indices will complicate things further.

Other system level settings to consider are statistics and memory settings. Again, you should post your plans to better understand this better.